# Function I created doesn't save result to text file

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

We have a exercise in which we are told to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and save the result in a new text file.But I do not get result saved in the text file.Can anyone point-out where I am going wrong?

Here is the code:-

```
temperatures=[10,-20,-289,100]
file = open("temperature_result.txt",'w')
def c_to_f(c):
    f=c*9/5+32
    for t in temperatures:
        return((c_to_f(t))
    file.write(str(c_to_f(t)))
file.close()
```

I get this error in the terminal:-

```
File ".\python_to_ttx.py", line 7
    file.write(str(c_to_f(t)))
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. I corrected it in my answer, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```py
temperatures=[10,-20,-289,100]
file = open("temperature_result.txt",'w')
def c_to_f(c):
    f=c*9/5+32
    return f
for t in temperatures:
    file.write(str(c_to_f(t)))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `with` method:

```
def c_to_f(c):
    f = c * 9 / 5 + 32

    return f


def write_file(file, temperatures):
    with open(file, 'w'):
        for t in temperatures:
            file.write(str(c_to_f(t)))
        file.close()


temperatures = [10, -20, -289, 100]
file = "temperature_result.txt"

write_file(file, temperatures)
```